# what is causing wrong page number in TOC for orgmode latex export

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

System:

- Windows 10 x64
- Emacs 26
- Export using XeLaTex

I am working on a report in orgmode.  The table of contents is giving me weird behavior.  The page numbers are all lower than they should be by one.  For example see the below text for an org document.  If I export this as a pdf, then the table of contents shows section one as starting on page 1, even though it starts on page two.  What is causing this and how do I fix it?

[image]

```
#+TITLE: A title
#+AUTHOR: An author
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

* Abstract
    :PROPERTIES: 
    :CUSTOM_ID: abstract
    :UNNUMBERED: t
    :END:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
tempor scelerisque magna, et varius leo pellentesque sit
amet. Phasellus aliquam pulvinar felis, fermentum commodo quam
tristique viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam pellentesque arcu in
justo fermentum, vel molestie metus fringilla. Nulla lorem risus,
efficitur vel porta id, tincidunt aliquam nunc. Mauris eros magna,
molestie et porttitor in, dignissim vitae lorem. Etiam lorem sapien,
rutrum nec aliquet sit amet, malesuada et tortor.

#+BEGIN_QUOTE
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
tempor scelerisque magna, et varius leo pellentesque sit
amet. Phasellus aliquam pulvinar felis, fermentum commodo quam
tristique viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam pellentesque arcu in
justo fermentum, vel molestie metus fringilla. Nulla lorem risus,
efficitur vel porta id, tincidunt aliquam nunc. Mauris eros magna,
molestie et porttitor in, dignissim vitae lorem. Etiam lorem sapien,
rutrum nec aliquet sit amet, malesuada et tortor.
#+END_QUOTE

#+TOC: headlines 4

* Section One

Some Text

** Subsection

** Subsection

* Section Two

** Subsection

** Subsection

* Section Three

** Subsection

** Subsection
```

Comment: FWIW, I get the right page numbers on Linux with Org mode version 9.1.14+ (updated from git two days ago) and xelatex based on XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996.

Comment: Fascinating, I will give that a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only compiling the latex file twice, but it needed to compile three times.  I changed the relevant code in my init.el file from:

```
(setq
    org-latex-pdf-process
    '("xelatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
      "xelatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

to:

```
(setq
    org-latex-pdf-process
    '("xelatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
      "xelatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
      "xelatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

Comment: Nice find - but since you can never know how many times is enough, you might want to investigate `latexmk`. My `org-latex-pdf-process` is set to ` ("latexmk --shell-escape -pdf -xelatex %f")`.

Comment: @NickD, thanks for the tip, I will definitely check that out